# MinGW w64 windows library eclipse (app crash)

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows

I'm trying to get C++ working properly in Eclipse but it seems that anything except the normal MinGW is failing and I have no idea what I'm doing.

Reason I'm trying this is because MinGW complains about `to_string()` not existing in the std library and I've read that this was fixed in MinGW-w64.

I've downloaded MinGW and MinGW-w64 to separate folders, currently MinGW is included in PATH.
When I change my project properties [C/C++ Build -> Environment] variables to go with MinGW-w64 the stuff still builds but crashes when I try to run it.

I'm trying to build a win32 app (`#include <windows.h>`)
Flags in [C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous]: `-c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -mwindows`

I've also included a Pre-build step: `windres ../src/resources.rc -o ../Resources/resources.o`

And for some reason it compiles without error, but when I try to run the binary.exe it just crashes (which it didn't with normal MinGW).

---

I've also looked into Cygwin but I have no idea what packages to download and I can't even find the std library, let alone the windows library, in the massive massive list of installable packages.

I also don't want to use Visual C++ because that requires you to install Visual Studio (an IDE I loathe because of reasons(yes, multiple))

I'm doing the minor "Games Programming" and my school is giving us a crash-course C++ (which exists of six 3 hour long lessons to get a grasp of the basics) to use in building a simple game application. Problem is the teachers are Visual Studio fanboys and don't really know anything outside of that environment (most of 'em don't really seem to care either for that matter).

I'm having a lot of trouble setting this up with no prior experience in C++ and a very janky C++ support for windows. ( I do know my fair share of Java (in Eclipse) and a bit of C# )

---

I've been searching for at least an hour without any results.

If I forgot to write down stuff or am being a total idiot here please do enlighten me.

Any help is much appreciated

---

<strike>Edit: I'm suddenly getting other error output</strike> <- forgot to clean before building

Edit edit: the error:
[image: app error]

(hi is the icon)

---

Another Edit:

if I debug it breaks at `No source available for "main() at 0x4081a9"` which makes sense because I didn't make that kind of main because I'm writing a windows app. if I press continue it runs (what?) but then when I close it I see the following output:

`C++ Win32.exe`

```
~"[Inferior 1 (process 7012) exited normally]
"
```

`gdb`

```
[New Thread 7012.0x1d14]

Temporary breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004081a9 in main ()
Quit (expect signal SIGINT when the program is resumed)
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the error/crash is a simple example of code?

Comment: I've used example code from here http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/simple_window.html (just copy pasted it) also updated question to show the actual error (I don't think it'll be of much use)

Comment: and if you click "Debug the program"?  MinGW includes a debugger (gdb).

Comment: ps Link to MS Visual Studio Community Edition 2013 http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs

Comment: @RichardCritten Updated my question to show what happens when I debug. And about Visual Studio: I quote "(an IDE I loathe because of reasons(yes, multiple))"